# Parsing xml with simple structure

Tags: python, xml-parsing

For some reasons I just can't extract the content of the xml below: Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

```
f='''<features>
    <name>Michael</name>
    <age>81</age>
    <dob>20/10/1925</dob>
</features>'''
```

Attempt:

```
tree=ET.parse(StringIO(f))
root=tree.getroot()
for x in root:
    print x.tag, x.attrib

Output:
name {}
age {}
dob {}
```

Ideal Output:

```
name {Michael}
age {81}
dob {20/10/1925}
```

Not really good at xml with python, thanks for your suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your elements do not have `attrib`s. Try `x.text` instead, although you will need to add curly braces if you really want the text in curly braces.

```
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
>>> root = et.fromstring(f)
>>> for x in root:
    print x.tag, x.text


name Michael
age 81
dob 20/10/1925
```